# Estimate on Probability of a standard normal variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In the book written by Karatzas & Shreve, at the page - 111; the authors have mentioned about a result:

> If $Z_{v}$ be a standard normal variable; then for $\epsilon \gt 0$ ; $\mathbb P (|Z_{v}| \leq \epsilon) \leq \epsilon$

I have computed :

$\mathbb P (|Z_{v}| \leq \epsilon) = 1 - \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx$ .

But, I am clueless how to show this quantity to be  $\leq \epsilon$ !!

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This trivially follows from upper bounding the distribution of standard normal. Probability density function obeys $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2)$ which is always upper bounded by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Now to obtain your bound
\begin{equation}
P(|Z|<\epsilon)=\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} f(x)dx\leq \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx\leq \int_{0}^{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2/\pi}}dx=\epsilon \sqrt{2/\pi}\leq \epsilon
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry of $f(x)=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ you have that $\int\limits_{\varepsilon}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}(\int\limits_{\varepsilon}^{\infty}f(x)dx+\int\limits_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}f(x)dx)$. Now the limit as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$ will give you the integral of $f(x)$ over all of $\mathbb{R}$ which is a classical result and will solve your problem.